# How to get error or warning when gps off while monitoring reason(geo Fence)?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am trying to implement Geo Location monitoring(Geo fence) and following

[this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial). My concern is if after setting region I turned of GPS, is there any way I can get warning or error about GPS turned off?

I wrote these Methods

- monitoringDidFailFor
- didFailWithError

But Couldn't find any Error or warning

Please guide me.

Edit 1:- here disabling GPS is mean to disable location from settings

Comment: I would suggest to check the "Continue Discussion" section in the article itself and add your comment as a question, the guys there are pretty nice and probably you will get a respond.

Comment: @AhmadF thanks for your suggestion buddy but they already closed that discussion 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable GPS (and GPS is not required for geofencing, by the way), so I assume you are referring to location services authorization (Never/When in use/Always).

I suggest you implement and watch for didChangeAuthorization in location manager delegate protocol:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423701-locationmanager

Just keep in mind that this method is not called when your app is suspended (and it is for the most of the time). It will get called when your app goes into background or foreground mode, which might never happen, as disabling location services will prevent geofences from triggering.

Comment: you mean to say that while shutting down location from setting, My geofence will work fine?

Comment: no, geofencing will not work with location services disabled. What I am saying, is how your app may get notified on location authorization settings.

Comment: thanks for your response, actually "didChangeAuthorization" notify me when app is again in active mode. but I want to notify In background mode

Comment: you do get didChangeAuthorization callback when in background. I assume you are referring to suspended mode instead. An like I said, with location services disabled you never get back into background mode  with geofence triggering. You may want to use background refresh to periodically wake up your app by providing fake new data and check authorization status. No sure how this fits App Store policies, though.